# Массовая замена в строке по ключу массива

Tags: javascript

Требуется лаконичное решение по замене всех вхождений имен ключей массива в строке. Решение не должно быть громоздким. Символ `%` можно заменить на любой удобный. Спасибо!

```
var dict = {
  'key1':'программирование',
  'key2':'задача',
  'key3':'решать',
  'key4':'меньшие задачи'
};
var str = "Динамическое %key1% — это когда у нас есть %key2%,"
        + "которую непонятно как %key3%, и мы разбиваем ее на %key4%,"
        + "которые тоже непонятно как 'key3'";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Легко решается с помощью регулярных выражений.

```js
var dict = {
  'key1': 'программирование',
  'key2': 'задача',
  'key3': 'решать',
  'key4': 'меньшие задачи'
};
var str = "Динамическое %key1% — это когда у нас есть %key2%, которую непонятно как %key3%, и мы разбиваем ее на %key4%, которые тоже непонятно как %key3%.";

str = str.replace(/%key([0-9])+%/g, function(match) {
  return dict["key" + /%key([0-9])+%/g.exec(match)[1]];
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Упростил малость. `for(var key in dict){ str = str.replace('%'+key+'%', dict[key]) };`